# Is there any error in my sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my `user_info` table but it's not working. In my `user_info` I have already taken some values from one activity and from another activity I want to take some more values but it's not working. I'm pretty sure that there is no error in my Java code.. is there any error in my query?

```
$db_name = "db";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

$name = $_POST["user"];
$user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
$Gender = $_POST["Gender"];
$contact = $_POST["contact"];
$address = $_POST["address"];

$sql_query = "UPDATE user_info SET name='$name', Gender='$Gender', contact='$contact', address='$address' WHERE user_email='$user_email'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You mean beside the obvious security issues?

Comment: yup... because my insert query is already working

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: no... everything is fine but value is not changing in my database

Comment: have you checked `$_POST` values?

Comment: As @fusion3k said, check your `$_POST` variables. You're also using a [Mysql Reserved Word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), which will cause your query to fail. Wrap `name` in back-ticks -> `\`name\``.

Comment: Output your query and put it in phpMyAdmin. There you will see errors if some occur. But please, please do queries the right way (MySQL injection safe).

Comment: @Darren `NAME` no `(R)` next to it, unlike `NATURAL (R)`. `name` is a "keyword" and not a "reserved" word. *Two different animals* here ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- gahhhhhh Owe you a coffee ;-)

Comment: the error's `mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)` <<< there. No semi-colon. probably in conjunction with your POST arrays too, so check that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - if it's POST array related, the missing form is guesswork.

Comment: @Darren Make it count, and make it a double shot.... *of Espresso* ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: and use this too http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and post your HTML form while you're at it. I won't be staying here much longer.

Comment: Love it when they just "leave" eh @Darren ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's what makes stackoverflow.....stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: *sigh* @Darren I guess so. well... check out my comment to the guy. I'm  gone watching TV. *ciao!*

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure without seeing you database table but "Gender" is capitalized while the other field names are lowercase. Just a shot in the dark here, otherwise your query looks fine.

Comment: the word Gender is capitalized also in database